# Page does not recognise my styles

Tags: html, css

Do you have any ideas why sass does not recognise the child and creates new block instead?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="menu_inside">
    <a href="#" class="menu_link">Map</a>
    <a href="#" class="menu_link">Users (8 / 39)</a>
    <a href="#" class="menu_link">Events</a>
    <a href="#" class="menu_link" id="menu_content">Content
        <div class="menu_div_dropdown">
             <a>sdfsd</a>
        </div>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="menu_link">Setup</a>
    <a href="#" class="menu_link">Logs</a>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.menu_inside {
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
}
.menu_inside .menu_link {
  color: #353434;
  font-size: 11px;
  border-right: 1px #cecccc solid;
  float: left;
  min-width: 53px;
  padding: 10px 20px 9px 20px;
}
.menu_inside .menu_link:first-child {
  border-left: 1px #cecccc solid;
}
.menu_inside .menu_link:hover {
  background-color: #FFF;
}
.menu_inside #menu_content .menu_div_dropdown {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
}
.menu_inside #menu_content:hover .menu_div_dropdown {
  display: block;
}
```

I checked on inspect element on chrome and it shows that my sdfsd is in the new block but not as a Content child. If I remove the a from **sdfsd** it shows everything OK. Any ideas? Thank you

Comment: Unless you have a Sass->CSS compilation issue, **only post the compiled CSS**

Answer (score 2):

You can't have a div inside an anchor tag... block element inside an inline element is semantically incorrect.  On top of that, you have an anchor tag within an anchor tag.  Also semantically incorrect.  Either make the div a span and remove the inner anchor, or rewrite your code to something else.

**UPDATE**
I stand corrected for HTML5...

> HTML 5 states that the `<a>` element "may be wrapped around entire paragraphs, lists, tables, and so forth, even entire sections, so long as there is no interactive content within (e.g. buttons or other links)".

But your code is still wrong based on the fact that you have a link within another link.  You still need to fix that.

Comment: So I changed <a> to div where is content and it works now. :) Thx for the post I didn't know that.

Comment: No problem... but you should mark this answer as correct so other people know it's all set.